# IS there a way to get MODIS tiles as a function of lat/long in R?

Tags: r, coordinates, tile, r-modis

I'm looking for a way to automatically return the MODIS tile (e.g. h12 v4) as a function of longitude and latitude.

I was hoping the MODIS package could do it using getTile(***). I see there's a nice GUI when I use getTile() but I'm looking for an automatic method as a function of long/lat.

thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good suggestion! This is currently included in the **MODIS** 'develop' branch, and it will definitely be part of future package versions (starting with **1.1.4**). Until the next CRAN release, simply install the current 'develop' version from GitHub and see if this works for you:

```
# devtools::install_github("MatMatt/MODIS", ref = "develop")
library(MODIS)

## set point coordinates (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt)
dat = data.frame(lon = 8.682222, lat = 50.110556, loc = "Frankfurt am Main")
pts = sf::st_as_sf(dat, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

## get overlying tile
tls = getTile(pts)
tls@tile
# [1] "h18v03"
```

One important caveat, though: at the moment, this only works with **sp** (ie. `Spatial*`) and **sf** point inputs.

Comment: Great thanks for the solution :) I will try it out hopefully soon.